# Python - Assign a default string to 1 and 0

Tags: python, default

I'm working with Python for an application where we need to close and open doors. The values to open and close are 0 and 1 accordingly, these are commands and can not be changed, but it can be confusing to the user to see 1 or 0 (we want to make it more user friendly since it's a beginner application). Is there a way to define 1 as close and 0 as open so when sending the command to the microcontroller but when coding we use/see open or close?

I was thinking to use a dictionary but it would be good to define them at the beginning of the program so we don't need to change it every time.

Thanks!

Comment: I was about to suggest a dictionary myself, but I don't understand what you mean by "I was thinking to use a dictionary but it would be good to define them at the beginning of the program so we don't need to change it every time."

Comment: e.g. `commands = dict(open=0, close=1)`

Comment: Maybe `Enum` is what you need: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html. It gives you constants with human-readable string representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we use Enum for this case?

```
from enum import Enum
class DoorStatus(Enum):
     OPEN = 0
     CLOSE = 1
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Comment: Thanks! Didn't now about enum. Is perfect for this!

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use booleans for this (True and False) `True` could be open and `False` could be closed. You could assign `True` and `False` to the `door` variable depending on the user input. For example :

```
"""expected inputs are 'open' or 'close'. lower() translates the input to lowercase, so if someone enters 'OpeN' or 'cLOse' by mistake, it doesn't affect the program"""


#loop below will constantly ask for user input until they type an invalid input

while True:
    action = input('choose whether to open or close the door: ').lower()
    
    if action == 'open':
        door = True
    elif action == 'close':
        door = False
    else:
        print('I\'m sorry, ' + action + ' is not a valid action')
        quit()

    if door == True:
        print('door is open')
    else:
        print('door is closed')
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes it would be easier but the application we are doing is for people that have never programmed before so we are trying to make it as much explicit as possible